# Couchdb Upload Image via Httpclient

Tags: java, android, apache, curl, couchdb

I build An Android app with `couchdb`, i tried to uploaded image to the `couchdb` document with this function:

```
    public JSONObject uploadPicture(PutAttachment putAttachment) {
    JSONObject obj = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(baseUrl() + putAttachment.getDbName() + "/" + putAttachment.getDocName() + "/attachment?rev=" + putAttachment.getRev());

        ByteArrayEntity img = new ByteArrayEntity(putAttachment.getByteImg());
        httpPut.setEntity(img);

        httpPut.setHeader("Content-Length", "" + (int) img.getContentLength());
        httpPut.setHeader("Content-type", "image/png");
        httpPut.setHeader(authenticate());
        HttpResponse response;

        response = httpclient.execute(httpPut);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {

            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            obj = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));
            instream.close();
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return obj;

}
```

And i don't know why but every time i get `ClientProtocolException`

After

```
httpclient.execute(httpPut).
```

Someone know

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with it today. 
After studying this: [How to put image attachment to CouchDB in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852809/how-to-put-image-attachment-to-couchdb-in-android)

I got something like this in the end:

```
public static HttpResponse makeUpdateRequest(String uri, Bitmap bmp) {
    try {
        HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(uri);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
        ByteArrayEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(stream.toByteArray());
        entity.setContentType("image/png");
        entity.setChunked(true);
        httpPut.setEntity(entity);
        return new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpPut);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And called it in the floowing way:

```
    HttpResponse updateResponse = makeUpdateRequest(
            AppConfig.WEB_SERVER_DB_URI + uuid + 
            "/attachment?rev=" + revId, bmp);
```

This is a good reading:
http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Inline_Attachments